# Composite component recursion

Tags: jsf, nested, composite-component, state-saving

I want to do a recursive call to the composite component. Those. something like

```
<composite:interface componentType="myComp">
    ...
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <span id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <c:if test="#{cc.showMyComp}">
            <cust:myComp />
        </c:if>
    </span>
</composite:implementation>
```

But jstl in this case does not work correctly and ajax requests do not work inside the nested component. If I write in WEB.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then everything works, but my component is embedded in an application where partial state saving is used. How correctly to do recursion in composite component? I use jsf MyFaces 2.0.

Comment: Tried MyFaces 2.1.x? Or 2.2.x?

Comment: I've noticed a similar problem with Mojarra 2.2.12. Can't you use `<ui:fragment rendered="#{cc.showMyComp}">` instead of `<c:if>`? This solved the situation for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not use anything other than MyFaces 2.0, this is the target execution environment. If you replace `<c:if>` with `<ui.fragment>`, you get a StackOverflowError.